# Booting from Windows 8 DVD fails to give boot menu

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have Windows 8 32-bit, and want to install the 64-bit version using the 64-bit DVD.

Not having another Windows 8 DVD to create a recovery disk from, I thought I'll insert the 64-bit DVD and boot from there, then format C:, but booting from DVD only gives me the Windows logo, then proceeds to boot into my 32-bit Windows on my hard drive.

How do I boot from the DVD, so that I can format C: and install the 64-bit Windows 8?

Used to be so easy under Windows XP!

Comment: Have you created the DVD yourself (using the ISO image)? It's possible that there was some error while burning the DVD. I would either re-burn a DVD or (better) create a bootable USB stick.

Comment: Yes, I burned the ISO image myself.  Will take your advice and burn it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue - plugged in a wired keyboard and pressed a key when the 'Press Any key to boot from CD' is showed on the screen.
Windows 8 x64 setup worked after that.

I think my motherboard doesn't work well with wireless keyboards at POST.

Used the Windows 8 x64 DVD to clear C: and it installed fine.

Motherboard is an Asrock 939Dual.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must switch to your DVD device as first at bootload. If this won't help, make sure your DVD with Windows has bootloader to load from 'scratch', if no, just use some software like `ultraiso` or `win7tousbtool` (name might slightly differs) to burn it to flash drive and install.

Comment: It is already booting from DVD - it's just that after reading from DVD, the blue Windows logo comes up, then it starts my 32-bit Windows 8 on my hard drive.

Comment: if you would load from your windows8dvd you'd get into install process or encounter some error. Do you see spinning icon under windows logo?

Comment: Yes, blue Windows logo comes up --> spinning icon for a few seconds --> Existing Windows 8 32-bit boots up!!

Comment: is there any possible way for dvd disc to be damaged?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if you can boot another PC successfully with the DVD and reach the first install screen.

I assume since you're anyway doing a clean install when switching architectures, you must have backed up all your personal data, right? If not, boot from a Linux LiveCD/USB, copy your data to an external HDD, then use GParted to delete and recreate the Windows partition. Now you should be able to boot from the DVD and install to that partition.

Remember that if your system's storage controller requires SATA/AHCI/RAID drivers for Win8 Setup to recognise the HDD, you'll need to make sure you have those available on a USB stick to provide during the installation process. See [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9573-sata-driver-load-windows-8-setup.html) for instructions.

Comment: I don't have another PC to test that.  Yes clean install - don't need that partition anymore.  I'm not too familar with Linux - is there a Windows equivalent?  I have a Win XP CD, WinME floppy that I can use.

Comment: [XP Setup might help](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313348), but it's getting awfully long in the tooth and I would recommend you use something like GParted. There's nothing to it really, it has a simple [GUI](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php), but if you are at all in doubt don't risk your data and ask someone knowledgeable to do it for you.